Computing the coherent cohomology of a quasiprojective variety
I have a quasiprojective variety given by some explicit quations. How do I compute its coherent cohomology (with coefficients in the structure sheaf)? Do I use the Cech complex for an open affine cover of my quasiprojective variety? Or do I use a long exact sequence with local cohomology? Can this be done using a computer algebra system? Macaulay2 only seems to have an option to compute the cohomology of a projective variety with coefficients in a coherent sheaf.
